# Is there a "correct" way to sync databases between live and dev servers?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, git, version-control

I'm usually using git as the version control system to my WordPress code. But there's something missing from git. I can sync my project's files easily, but syncing databases is always a huge pain.

**Is there a "correct" way to sync databases between live and dev servers?**

I could include a database dump to the version control and update it every time, but that doesn't seem intuitive. Especially when in some cases WordPress tends to save information concerning the live server to the database.

P.S. I'm not talking about database structure, since there are ORM techniques for that, but the actual content of the pages.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming, but deployment practices. Belongs on [wordpress.se].

Comment: @brasofilo I disagree, because this question can be applied to any CMS. Or to any coding project in general that involves a database.

Comment: Anyway, some good resources: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deployment?sort=frequent&pagesize=15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try my script: https://github.com/jplew/SyncDB

> SyncDB is bash deploy script meant to take the tedium out of synchronizing
>   local and remote versions of a Wordpress site. It allows developers working in
>   a local environment (eg. MAMP) to rapidly "push" or "pull" changes to or from
>   their production server with a single terminal command.

I migrate content back and forth between live and dev constantly, so I reduced the process down to a single shell command:

```
./syncdb
```

Comment: It's awesome this script also solves the uploads folder problem with rsync.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a master-slave replication or master-master replication in MySQL.

**Master-slave replication**

- The production server will be master server and the development server will be slave server. Master server will pass new data to slave server. However, if you make change at slave server, it will not update to production server.

**Master-master replication**

- Setup both server as master, if production server changes, development server will change as well and vise versa.

### Further reading

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-howto.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Comment: I think most "web hotel" services prevent any connections to the MySQL server from other addresses than the localhost. Is there a solution, if I'm using a local dev server on my own computer?

Comment: There always is a solution, but it is not as easy as what MySQL in-built has offered.

Answer (score 0):

Due to WordPress being a production-ready system, most data is stored environment specific. Fortunately, migrating the database is rarely required (i.e. only when launching the site).

You can do so with the following steps:

- Export the source environment database
- Import the database to the destination environment
- Export the `wp_posts` table
- Replace any environment specific URLs (i.e. *dev.whatever.com* with *whatever.com*)
- Re-import the `wp_posts` table

Since most runtime configurations are in `wp_config.php` there's rarely a problem with the `wp_options` table. However, you can export it if you wish.

**Note:** This was taken from my article on [Configuring WordPress for Multiple Environments](http://viastudio.com/2011/02/08/configuring-wordpress-multiple-environments/).

There are also [plugins](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-dbmanager/) that help with this process.

Comment: "Migrating the database is rarely required". I disagree. What if a customer wants a new custom page that he can edit? You'd probably want to code it working and then push the new page to the production.

What if the customer modifies it and it breaks? You'd then want to push the customer's changes back to dev.

My point being, that when git handles all this for me at the code's side, is there any way to do it at the database side without manual syncing?

Comment: How often to you make a new custom page compared to the changes users make to the live site? *Rarely*. I've worked with WordPress for 5 years and taken a strong interest in its deployment. This works. You are welcome to find another way.